# Align text second line in MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem on aligning the texts on the second line. It needs to be aligned with the first line.

Codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/mediacard-material-demo-forked-92qlg?file=/demo.js)

```
<Card sx={{ maxWidth: 200 }}>
  <CardMedia
    component="img"
    height="140"
    image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
    alt="green iguana"
  />
  <CardContent>
    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
      Lizard
    </Typography>
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
        &bull; Hello how are you doing there?
      </Typography>
    </Box>
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
        &bull; Hi how are you doing there?
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  </CardContent>
  <CardActions>
    <Button size="small">Share</Button>
    <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
```

Comment: You can use unordered list

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036. wanted to use typography. can you fork my codesandbox?

Comment: @Joseph your example is already left align https://codesandbox.io/s/mediacard-material-demo-forked-8il0f
actually what you want?

Comment: @Khabir. you remove the dot? It should be there cause its like a list item. The "there" should be aligned with "Hello" or "Hi"

Comment: @Joseph I remove the dot just to check it. with or without dot it is already aligned that's why I asked what you actually want?

Comment: @Khabir. try to make your text longer so it would proceed to next line. the next line isnt aligned with the first word after the dot

Comment: @Joseph I got your point. what you get that is perfect. because when the line is break into second line it will be aligned with bullet point not with the first word of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bullet inside another `Typography` component and align it horizontally:

```
<Stack direction="row" gap={1}>
  <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
    &bull;
  </Typography>
  <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
    Hello how are you doing there?
  </Typography>
</Stack>
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [ul html element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) and add some styles.

```
...
      <CardContent>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
              Hello how are you doing there?
            </Typography>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="error">
              Hi how are you doing there?
            </Typography>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </CardContent>
      ...
```

Comment: Please fork my codesandbox